# Common network communications exceptions

Tags: java, android

I'm building a service bus for Android and I'd like to distinguish between hard exceptions and those due to network issues.  Broken connection, etc.  I was originally catching IOException, but that's obviously far too broad.  Some of those will be real file system issues local to the device.

Right now I have SocketException and ProtocolException, although the latter may not qualify.  Anything else you might expect in the normal course of mobile events?

Comment: ever find a decent concrete list?